# android - XMl error while its work in api 14 +

Tags: android, xml, api

please some tell me how to implement this xml code in api 8

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
```

this two attributes doesn't work in api 8  , and my application must work in api 8

any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exact two values of attributes, the application fails on pre-ICS android OSes. I verified by giving my own custom values(anything different from these) and it works like magic on every version.

Answer (score 4):

Replacing

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
```

with

```
android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
```

worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use dp instead

```
  android:minHeight="8dp";
  android:textSize="8dp";
```

Comment: android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" its equal android:minHeight="48dip"
and i think android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" equal 
 <style name="stylename">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>